# How to automatically increase the exponent in Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets

In a Google Spreadsheet, I put in the following numbers in a column, each line is an entry in the column.

```
100 
100*1.01
100*1.01^2
100*1.01^3
```

The highest exponent of 1.01 is 3 for now. But I would like to keep filling this column until the exponent of 1.01 is 30. I can only do it by filling each entry in the column manually. How can I do this easier?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Introduce the POWER function and use the ROW function to increment the exponent. Your second line would be,

```
=100*power(1.01, row(1:1))
```

Fill down and the `ROW(1:1)` will increment as *1, 2, 3, 4, 5, etc.*.

Comment: Add this to your first line and you won't have to drag down: `=ARRAYFORMULA(100 * POWER(1.01, ROW(C1:C4)-1))`

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra  -Good point. I had been thinking about the use of *x⁰* always equalling *1* regardless of the value of *x* but decided to take a more brick-by-brick approach. It would have made the formula a single one rather than different from A1 to A2 but I thought I might have a bit more obvious clarity with the verbose approach.

Answer (score 0):

After entering 100 into one cell (say, A2), I would put the following into A3: `=A2*1.01`, and [drag down](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/75509?hl=en) this formula to fill more cells in the A column.

(Although `row()` could be used for this, I prefer not to use it in formulas, to avoid them breaking when I add or remove the header row, etc.)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Your solution also works. But I actually like the row solution because the row index also tells me the exponent value while the cell index may not because my header row is not always 1