# How to automatically increase the exponent in Google Spreadsheet columns?

Tags: google-sheets

I have asked a similar question before
[How to automatically increase the exponent in Google Spreadsheet?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/77891/how-to-automatically-increase-the-exponent-in-google-spreadsheet)

But the new question is:

In a Google Spreadsheet, I put in the following numbers in a ROW, each number is an entry in the ROW.

```
100 100*1.01 100*1.01^2 100*1.01^3
```

The highest exponent of 1.01 is 3 for now. But I would like to keep filling this ROW until the exponent of 1.01 is 30. I can only do it by filling each entry in the ROW manually. How can I do this easier?

I tried

```
=100*power(1.01, COLUMN(1:1))
```

But this does not work.

Comment: Try wrapping that in an `ARRAYFORMULA`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
=100*power(1.01, COLUMN(A:A))
```

(That is, replace 1 by A). Actually,

```
=100*power(1.01, COLUMN(A:A)-1)
```

would be better, as it allows you to apply the formula to all cells, including the very first one.

---

Also, the answer I gave to your other question works equally well here:

Put 100 in a cell (for example, B4), then enter in the cell to the right `=1.01*B4`, and extend the formula to the right.

Comment: thank you again. Is there anyway that I can reflect the exponent value in the cell rather than relative value like the one you suggest?

Comment: So put A instead of 1?

Comment: Yes, that would do it.